# using eventpreventDefault getting Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, innerhtml, getelementbyid

I'm beginner on javascript, trying to learn. Here i have simple input, where user should write something, if user writes something it will print it out and if user do not write anything it should say 'Please write something.'.
in order to do that i want to use not operator (!).
any idea why i get this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null at myFunction  at HTMLFormElement.onsubmit`

here is my code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <form onsubmit="myFunction(event)">
    <input type="text" id="text">
  </form>

 <div id="demo"></div>

  <script>
    var arvo = document.getElementById("text").value

    if (!arvo) {
      function myFunction(arvo) {
        event.preventDefault();
        document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML = "text you typed: " + arvo;

      }
    } else {
      function myFunction(arvo) {
        event.preventDefault();

        document.getElementById(demo).innerHTML = "Please write something";

      }
    }
    console.log(arvo)
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: For future questions -> [How does the snippet editor work](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do)

Comment: Not revelant to the question, but you should usually use a seperate javscript file instead of using a script tag, because it makes your project more organized

Answer (score 0):

When you reload the page, the JavaScript code gets instantly executed.
Also, if you create a function in an **if** block, it will be only accessible there.
And the variable **event** is not defined.

You have to call the **if-else** in the function.

Solution:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form id="form">
<input  type="text" id="text" >
</form>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function myFunction(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var text = document.getElementById('text').value; //get the value
if (text) document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Text typed: " + text; // if the text is something
else document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "Please type something"; // if nothing
console.log(text);
}
document.getElementById('form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction); //run the function when it's submitted. Event listeners are perfect for this
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helped!